# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name in managed bean

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have this managed bean based on this [tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html).

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/* include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.component.UICommand;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

// source http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html

@Named("SessionsController")
@SessionScoped
public class Sessions implements Serializable {

    /* Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver */
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;
    // Data.
    private List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList;
    private int totalRows;
    // Paging.
    private int firstRow;
    private int rowsPerPage;
    private int totalPages;
    private int pageRange;
    private Integer[] pages;
    private int currentPage;
    // Sorting.
    private String sortField;
    private boolean sortAscending;

    private static class ActiveSessionObj {

        /* Oracle table structure
        CREATE TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG(
        ASESSIONID VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL,
        USERID VARCHAR2(30 ),
        ACTIVITYSTART TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTIVITYEND TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTIVITY CLOB
        )
         */
        private String aSessionID;
        private String userID;
        private Date activityStart;
        private Date activityEnd;
        private String activity;

        public ActiveSessionObj(String aSessionID, String userID, Date activityStart, Date activityEnd, String activity) {
            this.aSessionID = aSessionID;
            this.userID = userID;
            this.activityStart = activityStart;
            this.activityEnd = activityEnd;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public String getaSessionID() {
            return aSessionID;
        }

        public void setaSessionID(String aSessionID) {
            this.aSessionID = aSessionID;
        }

        public String getActivity() {
            return activity;
        }

        public void setActivity(String activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public Date getActivityEnd() {
            return activityEnd;
        }

        public void setActivityEnd(Date activityEnd) {
            this.activityEnd = activityEnd;
        }

        public Date getActivityStart() {
            return activityStart;
        }

        public void setActivityStart(Date activityStart) {
            this.activityStart = activityStart;
        }

        public String getUserID() {
            return userID;
        }

        public void setUserID(String userID) {
            this.userID = userID;
        }

        private ActiveSessionObj() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }
    }

    // Constructors -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Sessions() {
        // Set default values somehow (properties files?).
        rowsPerPage = 10; // Default rows per page (max amount of rows to be displayed at once).
        pageRange = 10; // Default page range (max amount of page links to be displayed at once).
        sortField = "ASESSIONID"; // Default sort field.
        sortAscending = true; // Default sort direction.
    }

    // Paging actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void pageFirst() {
        page(0);
    }

    public void pageNext() {
        page(firstRow + rowsPerPage);
    }

    public void pagePrevious() {
        page(firstRow - rowsPerPage);
    }

    public void pageLast() {
        page(totalRows - ((totalRows % rowsPerPage != 0) ? totalRows % rowsPerPage : rowsPerPage));
    }

    public void page(ActionEvent event) {
        page(((Integer) ((UICommand) event.getComponent()).getValue() - 1) * rowsPerPage);
    }

    private void page(int firstRow) {
        this.firstRow = firstRow;
        loadDataList(); // Load requested page.
    }

    // Sorting actions ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void sort(ActionEvent event) {
        String sortFieldAttribute = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("sortField");

        // If the same field is sorted, then reverse order, else sort the new field ascending.
        if (sortField.equals(sortFieldAttribute)) {
            sortAscending = !sortAscending;
        } else {
            sortField = sortFieldAttribute;
            sortAscending = true;
        }

        pageFirst(); // Go to first page and load requested page.
    }

    // Loaders ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void loadDataList() {

        // Load list and totalCount.
        try {
            dataList = list(firstRow, rowsPerPage, sortField, sortAscending);
            totalRows = count(); //count the tablerows
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // Handle it yourself.
        }

        // Set currentPage, totalPages and pages.
        currentPage = (totalRows / rowsPerPage) - ((totalRows - firstRow) / rowsPerPage) + 1;
        totalPages = (totalRows / rowsPerPage) + ((totalRows % rowsPerPage != 0) ? 1 : 0);
        int pagesLength = Math.min(pageRange, totalPages);
        pages = new Integer[pagesLength];

        // firstPage must be greater than 0 and lesser than totalPages-pageLength.
        int firstPage = Math.min(Math.max(0, currentPage - (pageRange / 2)), totalPages - pagesLength);

        // Create pages (page numbers for page links).
        for (int i = 0; i < pagesLength; i++) {
            pages[i] = ++firstPage;
        }
    }

    // Getters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public List<ActiveSessionObj> getDataList() {
        if (dataList == null) {
            loadDataList(); // Preload page for the 1st view.
        }
        return dataList;
    }

    public int getTotalRows() {
        return totalRows;
    }

    public int getFirstRow() {
        return firstRow;
    }

    public int getRowsPerPage() {
        return rowsPerPage;
    }

    public Integer[] getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    // Setters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setRowsPerPage(int rowsPerPage) {
        this.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
    }

    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Returns list of ActiveSessionObj items starting at the given first index with the given row count,
     * sorted by the given sort field and sort order.
     * @param firstRow First index of rows to be returned.
     * @param rowCount Amount of rows to be returned.
     * @param sortField Field to sort the data on.
     * @param sortAscending Whether to sort data ascending or not.
     * @return list of ActiveSessionObj items starting at the given first index with the given row count,
     * sorted by the given sort field and sort order.
     * @throws DAOException If something fails at DAO level.
     */
    public List<ActiveSessionObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws SQLException {

        String SQL_LIST_BY_ORDER_AND_LIMIT = "SELECT * FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG WHERE ROWNUM >= ? AND ROWNUM <= ? ORDER BY ? ?";     

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";
        String sql = String.format(SQL_LIST_BY_ORDER_AND_LIMIT, sortField, sortDirection);
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList = new ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj>();

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, firstRow);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, rowCount);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, sortField);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, sortDirection);                   

            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            /* take the result from the SQL query and insert it into Array List collection */
            dataList = ActiveSessionsArrayList(resultSet);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e);
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }

        return dataList;
    }

    /**
     * Returns total amount of rows in table.
     * @return Total amount of rows in table.
     * @throws DAOException If something fails at DAO level.
     */
    public int count() throws Exception {

        String SQL_COUNT = "SELECT count(*) FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_COUNT);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                count = resultSet.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            //close the connection
        }

        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Map the current row of the given ResultSet to ActiveSessionObj.
     * @param resultSet The ResultSet of which the current row is to be mapped to ActiveSessionObj.
     * @return The mapped ActiveSessionObj from the current row of the given ResultSet.
     * @throws SQLException If something fails at database level.
     */
    private static ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj> ActiveSessionsArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException 
    {
        ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj> al = null;

        try
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                al.add(new ActiveSessionObj(
                rs.getString("ASESSIONID"),
                rs.getString("USERID"),
                timestampToDate(rs.getTimestamp("ACTIVITYSTART")),
                timestampToDate(rs.getTimestamp("ACTIVITYEND")),
                rs.getString("ACTIVITY")

                ));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception x) {x.printStackTrace();}

        return al;


        /*
        CREATE TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG(
        ASESSIONID VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL,
        USERID VARCHAR2(30 ),
        ACTIVITYSTART TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTIVITYEND TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTIVITY CLOB
        )
         */
    }
    // select all button handle
    private Map<Long, Boolean> selectedIds = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

    // get the list from the JSF page
    public Map<Long, Boolean> getSelectedIds() {
        return selectedIds;
    }

    // call this method from the JSF page to delete the selected rows
    public String deleteAction() {

        // do something with the selected rows
        return null;
    }

    private static Date timestampToDate(java.sql.Timestamp ts)
    {
        Date d = null;
        try
        {
            d = new Date(ts.getTime());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return d;
    }
}
```

I get this error stack when I run the code in Glassfish:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.loadDataList(Sessions.java:193)
    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.getDataList(Sessions.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.list(Sessions.java:289)
    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.loadDataList(Sessions.java:190)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.list(Sessions.java:284)
    ... 58 more
```

I suppose that the SQL query is not correct or there is a problem with the prepared statement. What is the proper way to this query?

Best Wishes

**EDIT** This is the Oracle table:

```
-- TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG

CREATE TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG(
  ASESSIONID VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL,
  USERID VARCHAR2(30 ),
  ACTIVITYSTART TIMESTAMP(6),
  ACTIVITYEND TIMESTAMP(6),
  ACTIVITY CLOB
)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG

ALTER TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG ADD CONSTRAINT ASESSIONID PRIMARY KEY (ASESSIONID)
/
```

Comment: The problem is not in your code, is in your data source. Post your data source configuration. For more info, check here: http://www.orasite.com/errores/ORA/ORA-01745

Comment: Have you just tried to open a connection to your oracle db and close it using your data source?

Comment: Yes, Glassfish and Oracle are working without any problem

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG WHERE ROWNUM >= ? AND ROWNUM <= ? ORDER BY ? ?` I guess you need a colon in your ORDER BY sentence: `ORDER BY ?, ?`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The query is the problem, or rather the query parameters. You can only bind values, not column names or SQL keywords. So the last two parameters (after the ORDER BY) must be changed. You probably already planned for this. Otherwise the `String.format` wouldn't make sense.

```
String SQL_LIST_BY_ORDER_AND_LIMIT = "SELECT * FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG WHERE ROWNUM >= ? AND ROWNUM <= ? ORDER BY %s %s";

....

String sql = String.format(SQL_LIST_BY_ORDER_AND_LIMIT, sortField, sortDirection);
```

The following two lines then need to be removed:

```
preparedStatement.setString(3, sortField);
preparedStatement.setString(4, sortDirection);
```

Comment: In my case, I forgot the commas into the parentheses

Answer (score 11):

Look for predefined keywords in your query, eventhough you are not resolving it. Make sure all values in the query are correctly separated by a comma.

I have missed a comma and it cost me an hour before I figured it out.

Comment: The missed comma, Thank you. I spent hours looking for the wrong name or if I used a predefined keyword as column name.

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem on query part

1. In Query  (IN) or (NOT IN) condition values should not have more than 1000 values.
2. If you accumulate until 6(SIX) IN condition (i.e) the values in all condition should not more than 6635

Answer (score 0):

Seems I don´t have reputation to post a comment in Codo's answer.

His answer helped me, but if **sortField** and **sortDirection** are parameters that can be changed by the user, take care with **SQL Injection**.

How to prevent sql injection in this case? What is the best way?